# How to semantic/accessible create a list with "load more" button

Tags: accessibility

Here basic example of what I'd like to do:

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li hidden>Item 4</li>
  <li hidden>Item 5</li>
  <li hidden>Item 6</li>
  <li hidden>Item 7</li>
  <li hidden>Item 8</li>
</ul>
<button type="button">load more</button>
```

JS:

```
// Pseudo code
button.on('click').then(loadThreeMoreItems());
```

From the logic it's kind of easy and it would work fine with keyboard usage. But I'm not sure how get this more accessible for screenreaders, so the get noticed when new items are added to the list.

Does anyone have an option/kickstart of how to do this the right way?

In my search I found nothing. Maybe I look for the wrong keyword.

Thank you!

Comment: Are all items already loaded but just not yet visible, or are they retrieved from the server when the button is clicked?

Comment: Currently only hidden. AJAX loading might be a future option.

Comment: Please edit your question to be more UX focused, with fewer code references. Question about implementation are not encouraged here and could be hard to understand by all the UX specialists.

Comment: Hi, as you can see it was my first post here. My thought was, that accessibility is a topic for UX, even if a solution may be programmatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all items are already loaded, the "load more" function is there probably only for visual clarity and not for performance. When using a screen reader, there is no benefit in having to load more items, as this function only exists to have a nicer overview for people who can see. If this is true, all items can be made directly accessible for screen reader users but the "hidden" items can be made only visually hidden. Like this:

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li class="sr-only">Item 4</li>
  <li class="sr-only">Item 5</li>
  <li class="sr-only">Item 6</li>
  <li class="sr-only">Item 7</li>
  <li class="sr-only">Item 8</li>
</ul>
```

The `sr-only` class can be something like this:

```
.sr-only {
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    width: 1px !important;
    height: 1px !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    overflow: hidden !important;
    clip: rect(0, 0, 0, 0) !important;
    white-space: nowrap !important;
    border: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks. I never thought in this direction.
Do you know a way, when I have to do AJAX loading to announce new items to screenreaders?

Comment: You can add the `aria-live="polite"` attribute to the `<ul>` and just load the items in the list. But also `aria-describedby` that points to some help text (or the button if its label is clear enough).

Comment: Thank you for this hints.